# Cloudfront returning 502 for alternate domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have registered a domain via Route53 (example.io) and have successfully requested and verified an SSL/TLS certificate from ACM (example.io and *.example.io).

I have also configured example.io to return files from our S3 via CloudFront and it is working well.

Now, I need to create a CloudFront distribution that points to an application load balancer over HTTPS and a custom domain name.

I was able to create a CloudFront distribution that connected with our application load balancer and served over HTTPS. However, it is serving via the xxx.cloudfront.net URL.

What I need is to have the request served over the alternate domain name like api.example.io. Do I have to request another SSL/TLS certificate from ACM for api.example.io ?

I have tried adding the A records and the AAAA records in Route53 to point to the application load balancer with api.example.io but its not working. A black screen appears when i access api.example.io

Comment: No, 502 means there is something wrong with your app server. Check the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I took to solve this problem:

1. Ensure A records and AAAA records are created in Route53. The domain name should be the same as the one you created in CNAME (optional) portion of Cloudfront distribution.
2. Wait for a while to allow the DNS records to propagate throughout. For me, I waited a couple of hours.